# Как делать запрос, только при выполнении функции?(погода)

Tags: python, pyowm, openweathermap

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
API_TOKEN = '<TOKEN>'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['weatherNow'])
async def weatherNow(message: types.Message):
    from weatherNow import weatherNow
    await message.answer(weatherNow)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Мне тут нужно чтобы, библиотека обращалась к апи только при вызове функции
Вот кусок кода с мониторингом погоды

```
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils import config
from pyowm.utils import timestamps
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

condition_new = ('Сейчас в ' + new_city1 + ' ' + condition_upd + '')
temp_new = ('Температура ' + str(temp_upd2) + ' C°' + '')
wind_new = ('Ветер ' + str(wind_upd) + ' М/С' )

pogoda = [condition_new, temp_new, wind_new]
weatherNow = ('\n'.join(pogoda))
print(weatherNow)
```

Comment: Обернуть тот кусок кода в функцию. Импортировать функцию из файла в скрипт бота и вызывать

Comment: хмм,  но как я буду просить бота отослать результат?

Comment: Будете вызывать функцию, передавая в нее параметры, типа город. А OWM сделает запрос и результат вы вернете из функции

Comment: блин, точно ```return```  совсем забыл

Comment: Работает~
Спасибо, оставьте ответ пожалуйста, я его отмечу достоверным

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Мой ответ получится слишком общий :) Сделайте, пожалуйста, сами ответ с примером вашего кода :) У вас ведь снизу есть кнопка, что-то вроде ответить на собственный вопрос?

Comment: Хорошо, так и сделаю